# Angular docker-compose up not working

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a dockerized angular app which does not start when using "docker-compose up". I dockerized the application as I want to distribute it to fellow students etc.

The building of the image works just fine.

Please find the error message at the end of the post.

This is my Dockerfile for the angular-part:

```
FROM node:9.4.0

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app

RUN npm install --save

COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

This is the angular related part of my Docker-compose file:

```
angular:
    build: ../angular
    container_name: ng
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    volumes:
      - ../angular:/usr/src/app
```

I get this errror on startup.

```
angular@0.0.0 start /usr/src/app

ng serve -H 0.0.0.0

sh: 1: ng: not found

npm ERR! file sh

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! angular@0.0.0 start: `ng serve -H 0.0.0.0`

npm ERR! spawn ENOENT

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the angular@0.0.0 start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve -H 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas what I could change in the dockerfiles or the compose file.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I assume you have ng-cli or similar in your package.json. Don't you need to install that with -g (global) to make ng command work inside the container? Or if not you need to be in the project folder?

Comment: I have added the package.json

Comment: I changed the installation process in the docker file: RUN npm -g config set user root

RUN npm install --quiet --no-progress -g @angular/cli@latest

RUN npm cache clean --force    but now I get the error: node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
angular:
    build: ../angular
    container_name: ng
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    volumes:
      - ../angular:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up in a situation where I had to remove the volumes for my container

```
docker-compose rm -v angular
```

This was because I had mounted `node_modules/` to avoid overwriting these as we were mounting the js sources via a container<->host mount for hot reloading.